# Is it possible to use my router to extend any USB hardware?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, usb, ethernet

Using Windows 7 x64 Ultimate and an AT&T (Motorola) router 5031NV.

I want to use my USB devices in another room. I am already connected via Ethernet cable to the router and was wondering whether, instead of a NAS, it would be possible to use any USB device or even a USB splitter (Connected to the router)?

Comment: http://www.usb-over-ethernet.com/

Comment: Your question does not match your title (modem). Please clarify one or the other.

Comment: Is your modem a USB device?

Comment: @Moses Thank you, this is exactly what I spent ages searching for!

Comment: @BuiltonSin, consider posting an answer to explain how you solved your problem.  That would be helpful to others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [USB-Over-Ethernet](http://www.usb-over-ethernet.com/), which does exactly what you're asking:

> USB over Ethernet is a professional software solution allowing to use
>   USB devices remotely through a LAN, Internet or any other network
>   connection.
>
> USB over Ethernet allows you to share USB devices over IP. You can
>   connect to a shared USB device and use it just like it is plugged in
>   your machine. And there is no need to install USB device's driver on
>   the computer where it is physically plugged in.